# How do I get Robolectric working with the Android-Release Archetype?

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, robolectric

I am trying to get Robolectric to work with the Android-release-archetype located https://github.com/akquinet/android-archetypes/wiki/Android-release-archetype
I am having no luck so far
1. I have added the Robolectric dependancy to the POM.
2. I used the goals "clean install"
Then I get erros like these:

```
 [ERROR] /Users/Dewi/Dropbox/mac_projects/a-parent/application-it/src/main/java/dsdf/dsfsdf/a/test/ddd.java:[3,16] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/Dewi/Dropbox/mac_projects/a-parent/application-it/src/main/java/dsdf/dsfsdf/a/test/ddd.java:[4,23] package org.junit.runner does not exist
```

Can someone please try and get this archetype to work with maven and tell me how to do it?
Here is my test class:

```
package dsdf.dsfsdf.a.test;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class ddd {
       @Test
        public void asdasd(){
            assertThat(5, equalTo(1));
        }
}
```

Here is my parent POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>dsdf.dsfsdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>a-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>a - Parent</name>

    <modules>
        <module>application</module>
        <module>application-it</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pivotallabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-RC1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
                <artifactId>android</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-test</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.3</version>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                        <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                        <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                        <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                        <sdk>
                            <platform>7</platform>
                        </sdk>
                        <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                        <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.5</source>
                        <target>1.5</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <removeExistingSignatures>true</removeExistingSignatures>
                        <archiveDirectory />
                        <archive>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</archive>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <certs>true</certs>
                        <keystore>${sign.keystore}</keystore>
                        <alias>${sign.alias}</alias>
                        <storepass>${sign.storepass}</storepass>
                        <keypass>${sign.keypass}</keypass>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.pyx4me</groupId>
                    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.4</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                            <artifactId>proguard</artifactId>
                            <version>4.4</version>
                            <scope>runtime</scope>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <configuration>
                        <proguardVersion>4.4</proguardVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>performRelease</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>enforce-signing-properties</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>enforce</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <rules>
                                        <requireProperty>
                                            <property>sign.keystore</property>
                                            <message>The 'sign.keystore' property is missing. It must
                                                contain the path to the keystore used to sign the
                                                application.</message>
                                        </requireProperty>
                                        <requireFilesExist>
                                            <files>
                                                <file>${sign.keystore}</file>
                                            </files>
                                            <message>The 'sign.keystore' property does not point to a
                                                file. It must contain the path to the keystore used to sign
                                                the application.</message>
                                        </requireFilesExist>
                                        <requireProperty>
                                            <property>sign.alias</property>
                                            <message>The 'sign.alias' property is missing. It must
                                                contain the key alias used to sign the application.</message>
                                        </requireProperty>
                                        <requireProperty>
                                            <property>sign.storepass</property>
                                            <message>The 'sign.storepass' property is missing. It must
                                                contain the password of the keystore used to sign the
                                                application.
                      </message>
                                        </requireProperty>
                                        <requireProperty>
                                            <property>sign.keypass</property>
                                            <message>The 'sign.keypass' property is missing. It must
                                                contain the password of the key used to sign the
                                                application.</message>
                                        </requireProperty>
                                    </rules>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>linux</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>unix</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <rt.jar.path>${java.home}/jre/lib/rt.jar</rt.jar.path>
                <jsse.jar.path>${java.home}/jre/lib/jsse.jar</jsse.jar.path>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <!-- mac profile has to be after unix since running on mac will trigger 
            both -->
        <profile>
            <id>mac</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>mac</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <!-- absolute path -->
                <!--<rt.jar.path>/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Classes/classes.jar</rt.jar.path> -->
                <!-- or with JAVA_HOME /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/ -->
                <rt.jar.path>${java.home}/../Classes/classes.jar</rt.jar.path>
                <jsse.jar.path>${java.home}/../Classes/jsse.jar</jsse.jar.path>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>windows</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>windows</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <rt.jar.path>${java.home}/jre/lib/rt.jar</rt.jar.path>
                <jsse.jar.path>${java.home}/jre/lib/jsse.jar</jsse.jar.path>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

And here is the child POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>dsdf.dsfsdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>a-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>dsdf.dsfsdf</groupId>
  <artifactId>a-it</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>apk</packaging>
  <name>a - Integration tests</name>

  <properties>
      <!--
        When not running a release, we are deploying the plain artifact (so no classifier)
        This is overridden during the release.
      -->
      <zipaligned-classifier></zipaligned-classifier>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
      <artifactId>android</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
      <artifactId>android-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>dsdf.dsfsdf</groupId>
      <artifactId>a</artifactId>
      <type>apk</type>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <classifier>${zipaligned-classifier}</classifier> <!--  classifier set according to the ran profile -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>dsdf.dsfsdf</groupId>
      <artifactId>a</artifactId>
      <type>jar</type>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>release</id>
      <properties>
        <!--
          When running a release, we must deployed the final artifact (signed and zipaligned).
        -->
        <zipaligned-classifier>aligned</zipaligned-classifier>
      </properties>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>sign-application-it-apk</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>sign</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <sign>
                <debug>false</debug>
              </sign>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

</project>
```

Thanks

Comment: anyone?
I have spent ages on this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add dependency to JUnit in pom.xml

example:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks
but I have already done that
I know, I should have posted my POMS to start with
Could you have a look at what I am doing wrong please?
I have spent ages over this
Your help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to test my app with the same maven structure, same archetype...a mess.
Apparently the test scope didn't work with my configuration because, when the *-it module is separate, the executed main phase is never considered as `test` (if you check the log you will see that it is missing and, besides, the src/test/java in your modules are usually empty).
I am assuming this, because when I changed the scope of both robolectric and junit to "provided", something was happening, but I wasn't having my tests properly executed. Something was still missing (see [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375124/simbols-not-resolved-when-testing-with-eclipse-adt)).
I am talking in the past because I gave up and merged the *-it project into the main one (I'll leave the *-parent there for now). It is very weird though, because I have a little library with the very same structure and it runs Instrumentation test without flinching. In that case, no Activity is generated by the main project, just a simple jar library.